# iOS: Wait for an event of button during the loop

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm working on a small project in which I need to execute a LOOP to ask questions, and during the LOOP I need to wait for the answer from user before I can perform the next operation.

Any of you could help?

Comment: Which control are you using to get answer from the user? like UITextField, UITextView???

Comment: I gave user 2 Buttons : YES, NO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iPhone's object-oriented framework, Cocoa Touch, already includes the loop you need. There's a class called [NSRunLoop](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSRunLoop_Class/Reference/Reference.html) that does exactly what you require: it waits for events from the user interface (among other things) and then calls your code to handle the events.

So don't worry about building this loop yourself. [Apple has a tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphone101/Articles/00_Introduction.html) that shows how you can build an app that waits for user input and does work based on that input.

Comment: I would appreciate with an example of how to use that class, could you please!

Comment: Hi @VibolTeav, for your situation you won't need to interact with the run loop directly. I recommend trying out the tutorial to get an idea of how events work in iOS apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can set all your butons into disabled state:

```
[myButton setUserInteractionEnabled:false];
```

After loop is finished, just set it back to true state. This seems to be the easiest possibility.